# Shortcode plugins for own custom cms like wordpress shortcode plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, content-management-system, shortcode

I have created a custom CMS for my own and a plugin system that is working as I expected.

Now I want to create plugins based on shortcodes, 
eg:
    [gallery attr1=100 attr2="string"] and [mycode title='message' color='#F00']Hello World![/mycode]

I want to handle the above mentioned shortcodes in my CMS.
Functions will replace shortcodes with HTML and get & set attributes as parameters for mySQL queries or something else.

may be regular expressions will help, I am not expert in regular expressions. I would don't like to use such regular expressions if there are other smiler or good ways exist  .

CMS developed using PHP and mySQL.

I have visited the wordpress developers sites and got the concepts, I have already created functions that register or set plugins, menus, theme sidebars etc.

I think this info is enough to get the point as I can just explain in this way.

thank you in advance

Comment: is there a question here...cuz if there is i dont know what you are asking..

Comment: for eg: in page contents there are tags ([gallery id=1 title=photos]). I need a method that can find this kind of tags and call a function of that tag name (function gallery(array(id=>1, title=>photos))). their may be any closing tags and strings between it.

Comment: are you kidding me?...lol... "I need a method that can find this kind of tags and call a function"..what have you tried?..or should we write your code for you?

Comment: I want you to create a function that uses regex to find tags and return a array with that tag name, its attributes and contents between this and ending tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code solved the logic

```
function plugin_sortcode($contents) {
    global $SORTCODES, $DATA;

    foreach ($SORTCODES as $name => $fn) {
        $attr = array();
        preg_match_all("/\[" . $name . " (.*?)\]/", $contents, $matches);
        if ($matches[0]) {

            $code = $matches[0][0];
            if (isset($matches[1])) {
                $attrs = $matches[1][0];
                $attrs = explode(" ", $attrs);
                foreach ($attrs as $values) {
                    $attrs1 = explode("=", $values);
                    $attr[$attrs1[0]] = $attrs1[1];
                }
            }

            $data = $fn($attr, $DATA);
            $contents = str_replace($code, $data, $contents);
        }
    }

    return $contents;
}
```

Comment: Can you help with same function in C#?
I asked it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44815192/shortcode-parser-in-c-sharp

Also, what if there is a space in mid, for eg: [gallery id="1" text="My Gallery"]