# Shortcode parser in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, shortcode

This question was probably asked before but there are no proper solutions, at least I am unable to find one.

I have a CMS in C#, the article is saved in the database and what I need it while loading the article it should parse available shortcodes like Wordpress.

```
string str = "Hello there, show my name as [shortcodeX val="Garth"]";
```

What I need is some help to parse it based on the shortcode called.

```
public string shortcodeX(string val)
{
    return "hi" + val;
}

string str = ParseStringForShortCode(str);
```

I hope I am able to explain the requirement here and looking for some help

P.S.: I found something in PHP at [Shortcode plugins for own custom cms like wordpress shortcode plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237924/shortcode-plugins-for-own-custom-cms-like-wordpress-shortcode-plugins) but since I dont know PHP, its hard for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This seems what you need: https://github.com/aolde/shortcoder.

You can also install it via NuGet.